# How to fix the error message "Compilation error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'ezButton' and 'int')"?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to write some simple code to get a limit switch to fire illuminate a few LEDS, I haven't finished this yet as I'm stuck on this error message

"Compilation error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'ezButton' and 'int')"

Here is the snippet of code with the eror message:

```
void updateLEDS() {

if(limitSwitchPin == HIGH); {
  limitSwitchPin.loop();
  if(limitSwitchPin.isPressed()) {
    if(currentMillis - previousLED_2Millis >= blinkTime);
    LED_2 == HIGH;
 }
else if(currentMillis - previousLED_2Millis >= blinkTime); {
  LED_2 == LOW;
}
}
}
```

Here is the entire code:

```
//Libraries
#include <ezButton.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

//Constants
const float STEPS_PER_REV = 32;
const float GEAR_RED = 64;
const float STEPS_PER_OUT_REV = STEPS_PER_REV * GEAR_RED;
const int blinkTime = 500;


//Stepper Motor Pre-Setup
int StepsRequired;
Stepper steppermotor(STEPS_PER_REV, 8, 10, 9, 11);

//LED PRE-Setup
int LED_2 = 5;

//Switch Pre-Setup
ezButton limitSwitchPin(7);
//int limitSwitchPin = 7;

//Previous Variables 
unsigned long previousLED_2Millis = 0;
unsigned long  currentMillis = 0;

//==========================

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
int currentMillis = millis();

pinMode(LED_2, OUTPUT);

limitSwitchPin.setDebounceTime(100);

Serial.begin(9600);
}
//==========================

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
stepperMotor();
//readSwitch();
//updateLEDS();
}

//==========================

void updateLEDS() {

if(limitSwitchPin == HIGH); {
  limitSwitchPin.loop();
  if(limitSwitchPin.isPressed()) {
    if(currentMillis - previousLED_2Millis >= blinkTime);
    LED_2 == HIGH;
 }
else if(currentMillis - previousLED_2Millis >= blinkTime); {
  LED_2 == LOW;
}
}
}
```

I have never encountered this error before so any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: What is not clear about the error message?

Comment: Wait, you saying that made me go back and read my question with a fresh pair of eyes, I just found out how to fix this, I'm feeling stupid right now aha, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, next time, before posting, do that re-read and it may save you some time and effort, Good luck.

Comment: it is not C only aruino dialect of C++ and this error message is C++ related.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
 if( limitSwitchPin.getState() == HIGH) {
```

Two changes,

- use `.getState()`
- avoid the `;`